# When two proposition "to"s encounter

Tags: prepositions, relative-pronouns, ellipsis

> Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues **to which** category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong.
>
> > Context: [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/business/2018/09/27/makers-of-very-expensive-cars-want-to-be-luxury-goods-firms)

Grammatically, you need to have "**clues to** which..." and "**to which** ... belong ". So is "to" double duty here？

（My guess is that "clues to to which" is redundant, so the writer left out one "to"）

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the missing word here is not an additional "to", but an "as":

> Aston Martin’s IPO will provide further clues **as to which** category ultra-expensive carmakers really belong.

The phrase "as to which" is often used in contexts like this one. From [Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/as-to-something):

> **as to something**
>   a) concerning something
>   *advice as to which suppliers to approach*

We both agree on this, though: no writer would use *to to which* in this context.